# HikariCP - add properties to JDBC url

Tags: java, jdbc, hikaricp

For regular JDBC connection you can add the properties to the DriverManager:

```
url = "jdbc:postgresql://host:port/db?user=user&password=pass";

Properties props = new Properties();

DriverManager.getConnection(url,props);
```

for HikariCP it has `hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(url);`

How to add properties for the JDBC connection (not the HikariCP properties)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Hikari's [initialization](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#initialization), you can add property by using [config.addDataSourceProperty](http://static.javadoc.io/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/2.6.3/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.html#addDataSourceProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) method:

> ```
> HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
> config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/simpsons");
> config.setUsername("bart");
> config.setPassword("51mp50n");
> config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
> config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
> config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
> ```